# SQLite: How to simultaneously read data from stdin and table name from variable?

Tags: bash, sqlite

From bash, I want to pass to sqlite3 my TSV table from stdin while also passing the name of the table to import into from a variable. How can this be accomplished? For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

output_sql_db="$1"
input_tsv="$2"
table_name="$3

tail -n +2 "$input_tsv" | sqlite3 "$output_sql_db" '.import "/dev/stdin" ${table_name}'
```

Of course in this example, `${table_name}` does not get expanded correctly due to the use of `'` in the sqlite3 command. How should this be done? It seems all the answers I find only show to hand handle one or the other (data import OR passing table name).

Answer (score 1):

Use a bash heredoc, and decide when/where you escape input. At variable definition or command creation.

EDIT:

My point is to simplify the syntax/approach you're using, to something like.

```
output_sql_db="$1"
input_tsv="$2"
table_name="$3
importfile=$(tail -n +2 $input_tsv)
sqlite3 "$output_sql_db .import ${importfile} ${table_name}"
```

Comment: Do you have an example of how to do this? I have been using heredocs for other steps as well but could not figure out how to make it work in this case. I thought that both the heredoc and the piped file would be sent through stdin, which would cause conflicts, no?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in your example is the use of single-quotes around your command, which prevents variable interpolation. If you want to use variables, you need to use double-quotes.

Another (unrelated) possible problem is your use of `tail -n +2`. If what you wanted was the 2 last lines of your $input_tsv file, the proper syntax is `tail -2 $input_tsv`.

Finally, the name of your `$input_tsv` variable suggests that your input is Tab-separated. If that is the case, you need to tell sqlite that you don't use it's default separator `|` but a Tab character instead, which can be written as `$'\t'` in Bash.

So this rewritten version of your script should work :

```
#!/bin/bash

output_sql_db="$1"
input_tsv="$2"
table_name="$3

tail -2 "$input_tsv" | sqlite3 -separator $'\t' "$output_sql_db" ".import /dev/stdin $table_name"
```